# What shader can I use for stacked transparent boxes?

Tags: rendering, shaders, transparency

I have a cube build from red and green bricks

[image: Example Cube in Layout View]

I want the red as well as the green parts to be transparent, but I cant figure out what shader I should use.

My main problem is that during rendering, the parts where multiple red and green parts are behind each other the corresponding pixels just get darker.

Transparent BSDF Shader
[image: Cube rendered using Transparent BSDF Shader]
Principled BSDF Shader
[image: Cube rendered using Principled BSDF Shader]

Ideally I would only want the color to change e.g. (more green bricks => pixel more green; equal  red and green bricks => yellow pixel) and not the brightness of the pixel.

Is there a simple way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Are you confusing emission and absorption?  Red light + Green light may add up to Yellow light .. but (Not Red) absorption followed by (Not Green) absorption  does not add up to (Not Yellow) absorption.

Comment: Im not trying to say that the renderer is wrong in this case but that this is the effect (red and green mix proportionaly and dont lose brightness)   i would like to have. I understand that this is not how it would work in the real world with for example glass Bricks.

Comment: Looks like you may need to go to the Properties Editor's Render Properties tab, open the Light Paths panel and increase maybe total, transmission and transparent max bounces.  Beyond that the effect you're looking for is often qualified with a volume shader, since material shaders only consider the surfaces.

Comment: @MartyFouts okay, thanks i will take a look